# UIScrollView zooming to a specific area of an image

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, nslayoutconstraint

***QUESTION EDITED***

In the xib I have the current hierarchy:

- UIView (containerScroller)

  - UIScrollView (imageScroller)

    - UIView (imageContainer)

      - UIImageView (image)

For some reason I check the `UIScreen.main.scale` before starting to manipulate the image and scrollview and in iPhone 8 Plus / 11 Pro Max it's working properly (3x display). But in other iPhones (2x display) it's not working properly.

This is what I do:

```
let imageSize: Double = Double(AppConstants.Data.ImageSize.width)
let zoomScale = imageSize / self.question.zoomScale
let origImageSize = Float(imageSize) // 1200
let relativeFactor = Float(self.imageScroller.frame.size.width) / Float(UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
let widthForScroller = Float(UIScreen.main.bounds.width) * relativeFactor
let delta: Double = Double(widthForScroller / origImageSize)
let zoomTo = CGRect(x: (zoomPropsX * delta), y: (zoomPropsY * delta), width: (imageSize * delta) / zoomScale, height: (imageSize * delta) / zoomScale)
```

It gives me the wrong location of image. How can I add the scale factor into the calculations for it to work properly?

Comment: To get help on this, you need to provide a ***LOT*** more detail. Why is your image view embedded in a `UIView`? How are you setting up constraints and sizes? Why are you referring to `UIScreen.main.bounds` instead of the scroll view's frame? Here's a tip, though: Start Simple. See if you can get `scrollView.zoom(to rect: CGRect, animated: Bool)` to work with hard-coded values... then work on implementing the dynamic values.

Comment: I think that the best way to approach this is what you wrote here "Start simple". That's what I will do in order to get this right. Already getting some results...

Thank you!